# Linear decomposition of bounded linear functional.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $(f_n)_{n\ge 0}$ be s sequence of pointwise bounded linear functional in linear space $X$.

Prove that when $$|f_0(x)|^3 \le \sum_{n\ge 1}|f_n(x)|^3 < +\infty$$ there exists $\{b_n\}$ such that $f_0 = \sum_{n\ge 1}b_n f_n$.

I think it's an application of Hahn-Banach Extension Theorem, but I cannot find a way to apply it.